# Converting a long series of numbers in excel to a date format

Tags: excel, date

I have a long series of numbers in Excel that I have been given:
For example '20130116074506.000265-300'

And I need these numbers to appear in a date format. Now from what I can see, the format is kind of YYYYMMDD followed by timing details.

I could do this manually, but obviously with lots of records this will t ake a long time.
I have tried to format  the columns in to date and custom, I have tried various formulas to change this - such as:

=--TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00")
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))

But I get errors - I have spent a fair bit of time research online but have had no luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.
Kiwi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your trouble is if you use the `Left` and `Mid` function straight into the `Date` function then you are getting string results from `Left` and `Mid` which the `Date` function doesn't like.  If you convert it to Integers using `Int` then it should work.  Assuming the input text is in cell A1 then try this:

```
=DATE(INT(LEFT(A1,4)), INT(MID(A1,5,2)), INT(MID(A1, 7,2)))
```

Or you can use the individual `LEFT` and `MID` functions to break it into cells and read those in which will convert it to a number for you.

Comment: Brilliant that worked well, my next question would be - is there a simple way I can implement this to my entire spreadsheet - perhaps a macro?

Comment: :) It depends how your data is arranged really.  If it's in a single column then put it in the first cell to the right of your text and double click on the small square in the bottom right corner of the cell you've just entered it in and it'll fill the formula down.  Otherwise it really depends how the workbook is setup.

Comment: I don't think INT is required - most date functions in Excel can process text values from MID and LEFT equally as well as numbers, it's just a case of getting the correct numbers from the string, so this should work `=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))` as should `=TEXT(LEFT(A1,8),"0000-00-00")+0` - for the latter you need to format as a date

Comment: Wow, I thought the same but when I saw the question I tried the `=DATE(LEFT(A1,4), MID(A1,5,2), MID(A1,7,2))` without `INT` and got a `#VALUE` error so I assumed it was the string issue. I separated it out to individual cells and used the `Date` function from them.  I then reconstructed with the `Int`s in their and came up good.  Now I've tried it in a fresh workbook and it works fine.  Maybe I screwed up the initial character counts in the `Mid`s or something.  Good point though.